# В чем разница? "Дать всем" и "дать каждому"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, история

Два слова "всем" и "каждому". Порой их даже так и используют вместе - "дать  всем и каждому". В чём же разница ? Когда появился второй вариант, и для чего его создали ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В чём же разница ?

В нюансах употребления. Сравните: "Он помахал всем" (то есть толпе), "Он помахал каждому" (то есть отдельно махал сначала одному, потом другому).

"Все" чаще указывает на **совокупность**, допуская любые обобщения (Пример: "Все любят, когда к ним относятся хорошо"). "Каждый" обычно акцентирует внимание не на совокупности, а на конкретных её участниках, как бы подчёркивая значимость любого лица, пусть и не называя его лично.

При этом "каждый", как правило, требует при себе дополнительного слова. Каждый кто? Обычно мы называем некоторую совокупность, скажем, гвозди, а потом говорим, что каждый из них оказался гнутым. Кроме самого популярного случая, когда под "каждым" мы подразумеваем людей. Тогда в тексте уточнение можно и опустить. "Каждый — себе на уме" совершенно однозначно понимается читателем как фраза о людях, даже если в ней нет никакого контекста. Со "все" такое тоже прокатит, но довольно криво. Именно потому, что "все" — фраза о массе, не конкретизирующая.

> Когда появился второй вариант?

А какой из них второй, какой первый?

> Когда появился?

Оба слова восходят к глубокой древности и имеют как праславянские, так и иные, европейские корни, о чём можно почитать в этимологических словарях. При этом можно обнаружить интересную вещь: "все" этимологически родственно смыслам:

1) Выводок, размножение и пр.

2) Целый

Это лишний раз говорит о том, что слово указывает именно на совокупность.
Однако поиски корней вряд ли способны дать точный ответ на вопрос, когда появилось слово. Видимо, возникло раньше, чем было записано. Когда же ещё?

> для чего его создали?

Чтобы выразить вложенный в него смысл, о каком бы слове Вы не спросили. Оба они, хоть и похожи по значению, не синонимы.